# How to convert a string with unicode characters in a string with utf-8 hex characters?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, decoding, unicode-string

I'm trying (without success) to convert the following string (it has the `ł ={LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH STROKE}` character encodede in unicode):

```
Marta Ga\u0142szewska
```

in the following utf-8 hex form:

```
Marta Ga%C5%82uszewska
```

How I can achieve that conversion using Python and store the result in a variable like `variable = "Marta Ga%C5%82uszewska"`?

Comment: This style of encoding is generally for URLs, in which case you'd also need to encode the space (`Marta%20Ga%C5%82szewska`). Python UTF-8 encoding would generally look like `Marta Ga\xc5\x82szewska`. Can you explain what you're using this style of percent encoding for, and what rule you need for your encoding?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to convert the string and use it in an HTTP request (the resulting string has to be: Marta+Ga%C5%82szewska or Marta%20Ga%C5%82szewska).
Encoding the string in "utf-8" gives me:
 "Marta Ga\xc5\x82szewska"

 but I can'f figure any way to get end convert the '\xc5' and '\x82' characters in '%c5' anf '%82'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For URL-encoding, you want `urllib.parse.quote`:

```
import urllib.parse
s = "Marta Ga\u0142szewska"
q = urllib.parse.quote(s)

=> 'Marta%20Ga%C5%82szewska'
```

If you prefer `+` to `%20`, you can use `quote_plus`:

```
q = urllib.parse.quote_plus(s)

=> 'Marta+Ga%C5%82szewska'
```

Comment: This even does the utf-8 encoding, can't get much simpler.